# How to append my own error to the ErrorDict of a form in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm writing a Django website. I have a form like this :

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    user_name = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

and I like to do something like this :

```
def worker_login(request):
    form = LoginForm(request)
    if !form.is_valid():
        form['user_name'].errors.append(u'This username is not registered.')

    return render(request, 'WorkerLogin.html',{'form':form})
```

but no errors are added to the errorDict of the form, how should I append an error to an errorDict?

Comment: What Django version do you use?

Comment: my django version is 1.5.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add validation error to a form in Django 1.5/1.6 like this:

```
form._errors["user_name"] = form.error_class([u'This username is registered.'])
```

You can find an example in Django docs [using validation in practice section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).